# Triangle in a circle on a tangent line. Unknown variables.

Tags: trigonometry

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

I have a geometry, where a triangle lies on a tangent line.
I need to be able to define lengths l1, and l2 and angles a3,and a4, using the fixed values in the image. L,a1,a2 are fixed values, along with the center of the circle.
When changing the angles a1 and a2, you can vary the position of the circle and the tangent line. For a starting point we can assume a1=a2.

I'd like to be able to define all the unknown variables using the known variables.
I have tried lots of trig, but i always end up with too many unknown variables.
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

It is the  problem of Apollonius circle which is intersected by a circle containing angle $120^{0}$ in its minor segment. The tangent line is the angle bisector.

The problem is *indeterminate* unless $l_1/l_2$ is also given.

Comment: But in Solidworks nothing can be moved when a1 and a2 are fixed. This means the sketch is fully defined, and thus any additional dimensions cannot change the shape.